# ¿cómo crear una tabla con valores obtenidos de dos foreach diferentes? (php html mPDF)

Tags: php, html, foreach, table, mpdf

Tengo que crear una tabla con valores de diferentes consultas, cada consulta tiene el mismo numero de resultados, pero al imprimir los valores del segundo foreach no me salen en la siguiente columna de la tabla sino abajo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<tbody>';

foreach ($alumnos as $key) {
 $html.='
 <tr>
<td>'.$key[0].'</td>
<td>'.$key[1].'</td>
<td>'.$key[2].'</td>
<td>'.$key[3].'</td>
</tr>
';
}
foreach ($falta as $key) {
$html.='
<tr>
<td>'.$key.'
</td>
</tr>';
}
$html.='
</tbody>
```

ojo: entiendo que esto ocurre por el ciclo del foreach, pero no sé como resolverlo, agredezco opiniones y sugerencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como sabía que ambos array tienen la misma cantidad de datos, terminé concatenando los valores del segundo array dentro del primero de la siguiente manera:

```
 $alumnos=[];
  $valores=$_POST['seleccionar'];
if(!empty($valores) && is_array($valores)){
foreach ($valores as $key => $value) {
$alumnos[]= explode(",", $value);
}
}
else {
  echo "Los valores no fueron recibidos";
}
$faltas=$_POST['faltas'];
if(!empty($faltas) && is_array($faltas)){
foreach ($faltas as $key => $value) {
array_push($alumnos[$key], $value);
}
}
else {
  echo "Las faltas no fueron recibidas";
}
```

de esta manera el array $alumnos quedó con lo valores registrados, despues solamente imprimo con

```
 <tbody>';
foreach ($alumnos as $key) {
 $html.='
 <tr>
<td>'.$key[0].'</td>
<td>'.$key[1].'</td>
<td>'.$key[2].'</td>
<td>'.$key[3].'</td>
<td>'.$key[4].'</td>
</tr>
';
}
$html.='
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada el problema es que estas ejecutando dos `foreach` por separado lo cual no te dara la linealidad que buscas y por eso te los imprime todo hacia abajo la parte que te falta llenar nunca se llenara porque el segundo `foreach` seguira llenando abajo  de lo que lleno el primero.

Seria bueno que mostraras el codigo donde tienes las dos consultas para saber como puedo responderte

Pero si tus consultas sql tienen que ver con dos tablas relacionadas entre si, es mejor que hagas una sola consulta utilizando `INNER JOIN` algo asi

```
SELECT * FROM falta f
INNER JOIN alumno a ON f.codAlumno=a.idAlumno
```

`codAlumno` es la llave foranea y `idAlumno` es la llave primaria (Esto te funcionara si la tabla alumno esta unida con la tabla falta)

De esa manera unes la informacion de las dos tablas, y puedes sacar una sola consulta de esas dos

Comment: el asunto es que no solo hago dos consultas sino cuatro en total, 
la segunda consulta depende de la primera, en la primera obtengo el N°contro, nombre y apellidos del estudiante.
en la segunda foreach (N° de control, + id de la materia + periodo) entonces {
obtengo las faltas} (lo mismo para retardos) y lo mismo para permisos.

Comment: Muestra como son tus consultas para poder ayudarte, edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo de las consultas